# Backpressure for REST endpoints with Spring Functional Web Framework

Tags: spring-web, spring-webflux

If I understood correctly, HTTP endpoints implemented with Akka Streams apply backpressure to HTTP clients by not reading from the socket used for communicating with the client.

Is this also true for HTTP endpoints implemented with Spring's Functional Web Framework?

If not, how would I signal HTTP clients to slow down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Spring 5, with its Web Reactive module, [implements the reactive streams spec](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm) with [Reactor](http://projectreactor.io/). Supporting backpressure is part of it.

Note that both the annotation-based and the functional flavors use the same infrastructure, only the programming model differs.

Comment: Hi Brian! Thank you for your response. I am interested in the implementation of back pressure for HTTP endpoints using  Spring Functional Web Framework. As far as I know the RS spec, it's just about the "protocol". I couldn't find an answer in the Reactor docs as well. Did I miss something obvious?

Comment: At the HTTP level, backpressure is handled by reading/writing to buffers according to the request demand. It means OS buffers may fill up, then remote hosts won't be able to write to the socket. But indeed, the backpressure information is not transmitted across the wire. Some protocols like https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-io try to address this and bake the backpressure information in transport protocols.

Comment: Summing up, to make sure I got you right: This is implemented the same way as in Akka HTTP: if there is demand from downstream, "Spring" reads from the OS socket. If there is no demand from downstream (say e.g. the DB is busy),  "Spring" does not read from the socket. When further requests come in, the socket fills up continuously and clients will receive a timeout if it is full. But these request will not fill up the machine's memory leading to a crash in the end.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Akka HTTP internals, so I can't confirm. But yes, this descriptions fits the behavior.