# BackPressure in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest, spring-webflux

I want to apply backpressure on my application webservice. So that if number of request is high say more than `N` I can notify the client. Below is my controller

Before WebFlux

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tasks", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ResponseTaskModel> taskForUser(@RequestParam(value = "userId", required = true) String userId,              
@RequestParam(required = false) Map<String, String> userData) {
    ResponseTaskModel responseTaskModel = service.retrieveNextTaskForUser(userId.toLowerCase(), userData);
    return new ResponseEntity<ResponseTaskModel>(responseTaskModel, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

After WebFlux

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tasks/v1", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Mono taskForUserV1(@RequestParam(value = "userId", required = true) String userId,
                                                     @RequestParam(required = false) Map<String, String> userData) {
    return service.taskForUserV1(userId, userData);
}
```

And the service method I am calling is a blocking call to db with three queries, I'm using a postgres database.

Now how shall I apply backpressure on the `Mono` object returned?

Comment: Please have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772711/backpressure-for-rest-endpoints-with-spring-functional-web-framework

Comment: I don't understand the question. If the service you're using returns a `Mono`, it should not be blocking and it should support backpressure natively. The backpressure transformation is communicated within the reactive pipeline, but not over HTTP. Could you explain what you mean by "I want to notify the client" and "I want to apply backpressure"?

Comment: Lets say i have a sudden load then i want to throw exception that i cant process the request.

Comment: Any help i am stuck with this

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Comment: For now Postgres has non blocking driver